# Django -> queryset[index] Index out of range

Tags: python, django

I have a queryset that contains 2663 objects; when I try to access the objects with index 2662, I get an "index out of range" error. I'm looking for someone to explain to me why this is happening.

So:

```
queryset = User_Answers.objects.all()\
            .\
            select_related('answer', 'answer__question',
                           'answer__question__admin',
                           'answer__question__category', 'mobile_user')\
            .order_by('answer__question', 'mobile_user__id', 'order')


queryset.count() = 2663
```

There are 2663 objects; when I try get object with index 2662, I get this:

`queryset[2662]` -> {IndexError}list index out of range

Then I check this:

`queryset.last() == queryset[2661]` -> returns True

How can that be possible?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please don't create a question that just links to a screenshot of an error. There is a principle of [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so that people can help investigate the issue. Also see [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Please post your question and all related information in a proper format. Error message / traceback are expected to be text not an image.

Comment: @KlausD. check now

Comment: What is so special about object #2662? What exactly are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

From the docs for [`order_by`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#order-by)

> Here, there could potentially be multiple ordering data for each Event; each Event with multiple children will be returned multiple times into the new QuerySet that order_by() creates. **In other words, using order_by() on the QuerySet could return more items than you were working on to begin with - which is probably neither expected nor useful.**
>
> Thus, take care when using multi-valued field to order the results. If you can be sure that there will only be one ordering piece of data for each of the items you’re ordering, this approach should not present problems. If not, make sure the results are what you expect.